# Usar DataTables junto a un modal dinamico en laravel

Tags: jquery, datatables, modal

mi proyecto de laravel tiene implementada unas datatables, y estaba probando colocar también un modal que se abriera con los botones de la tabla. El problema es que, si bien funciona en los 10 primeros datos, los de las siguientes paginas dejan de funcionar y no abren el modal aunque todos los botones se crean por defecto con un foreach.

esto es el codigo relacionado:

```js
$('#tablaUsuarios').DataTable({
     'language' : idioma_espanol

});
        
$('.view_data').click(function () {
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      $('#eliminarUsuarioModal').modal("show");
});
```

```html
<!--Codigo de la tabla. -->

<table class="table" id="tablaUsuarios">
                        <thead class="thead-light">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                                <th scope="col">Empresa</th>
                                <th scope="col">Area</th>
                                <th scope="col">Tipo de Cuenta</th>
                                <th scope="col">Telefono</th>
                                <th scope="col">Fecha Creacion</th>
                                <th scope="col">Fecha Cambio Pwd</th>
                                <th scope="col">Activo</th>
                                <th scope="col"></th>
                                <th scope="col"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach($arreglo['usuarios'] as $usuario)
                            <tr>
                                <td scope="row">{{$usuario->IdUsuario}}</td>
                                <td>{{$usuario->Nombre}}</td>
                                <td>{{$usuario->login}}</td>
                                <td>@foreach($arreglo['empresas'] as $empresa)
                                    @if($empresa->IdEmpresa == $usuario->IdEmpresa)
                                        {{$empresa->Nombre}}
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                                </td>
                                <td>{{$usuario->Area}}</td>
                                <td>@foreach($arreglo['tipocuentas'] as $tipocuenta)
                                    @if($tipocuenta->IdTipoCuenta == $usuario->IdTipoCuenta)
                                        {{$tipocuenta->Nombre}}
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                                </td>
                                <td>{{$usuario->Telefono}}</td>
                                <td>{{$usuario->FechaCreacion}}</td>
                                <td>{{$usuario->FechaCambioPwd}}</td>
                                <td>
                                @if($usuario->Activo == 1)
                                    SI
                                    @else
                                    NO
                                    @endif

                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <form action="#">
                                        <input type="hidden">
                                    </form>
                                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('usuarioEdit') }}">
                                        @csrf
                                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ $usuario->IdUsuario }}" id="IdUsuarioEdit" name="IdUsuario">
                                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Editar</button>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="button" name="view" value="Eliminar" id="{{ $usuario->IdUsuario }}" class="btn btn-danger view_data">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                </table>
                
                
    <!--_________________Codigo del modal.______________________________-->
          
          <div class="modal fade" id="eliminarUsuarioModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="tituloadduser">Eliminar Usuario</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <form action="{{ route('usuarioBorrar') }}">
                        <div id="inputAppend" class="modal-body">

                            <label id="seguroEliminar">¿Esta seguro de eliminar al usuario?</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                            <input type="submit" value="Si"class="btn btn-danger eliminar_usuario">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que los botones son creados dinamicamente con la paginacion.  Para que funcione necesitas utilizar `on()` en un elemento fijo.  Algo asi:

```
$('#tablaUsuarios').on("click", '.view_data', function () {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#eliminarUsuarioModal').modal("show");
});
```

Comment: si funciono :O muchas gracias